# BluetoothGATTSetCharacteristicValue return Invalid Handle "E_HANDLE"

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to use BluetoothGATTSetCharacteristicValue to set a value for a given characteristic in a service. I read in the method documentation that it needs a handle to the service which I don't know how to obtain it.

I tried to use the "ServiceHandle" member of the BTH_LE_GATT_CHARACTERISTIC structure but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and I would like to share it here.

The only way to open a handle on the service is to use the UUID of the service instead of the UUID of the device while enumerating the devices using the method SetupDiGetClassDevs.

Please check the following thread for more details.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/65c9cf4e-e225-4fc3-8c2c-66cd2401d3ed/how-to-establish-a-connection-from-windows-8-pc-to-a-bluetooth-low-energy-device?forum=wdk